# How do I write an ARM subroutine and call it from within C

Tags: c, arm, inline-assembly

Suppose you have to write a subroutine in ARM assembly to print the values of an array but have to call that subroutine from within C. How would you go about that? Am I doing this right? If so how do I go about writing the subroutine in ARM

```
#include <stdio.h>

//ARM subroutine to print 
 array

--asm void printVal(char * 
board)
{ 
  ; Load array to register
  ; Print each character to 
    screen
  ;Exit     

}

//C code
int main(void)
{
   char board[] = {"1","2,", 
      "3", "4", "5"};
    //Call the subroutine to 
     print

    printVal(board);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using? How you handle inline assembly will vary. There is a decent introduction at [A guide to inline assembly for C and C++](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/inline-assembly-c-cpp-guide/index.html)

Comment: you want inline assembly or real assembly?

Comment: I'm using the ARM compiler aka the armcc

Comment: I'm trying to write an embedded ARM assembly routine

Comment: In GNU C you can use `__asm__("stuff")` at global scope as an alternative to a separate `.s` file.  Or you can use an `__attribute__((naked))` function to have a C prototype and the body is just an `asm` statement.

Comment: armcc inline assembly is not real assembly, but rather a compiled language similar to assembly.